# Stop function calling in tabs

Tags: android, json, listview, tabs

I have 3 swipes tabs(A,B,C) in my android. When comes to tabs c, I have a function `RetrieveData()`, used to retrieve the data from `MySQL` and load into `listView`.

Assume in MySQL I have one row data only, when comes to c, the data will be loaded into listView (one list only). When I swipe to Tab A and swipe to C again, the list become 2 now. 
Is there a way I can make the `RetrieveData()` only call one times ?  Thanks.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View edit_details = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_work_details, container, false);
       // EditDetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        listViewUpdate = (ListView) edit_details.findViewById(R.id.listViewEdit);
        totalHours=(TextView)edit_details.findViewById(R.id.hour);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            ID = bundle.getString("ID");
           RetrieveData(ID); // retrieve data from MySQL
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Details" + ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

**TabAdapter**

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(index == 0) {

            Fragment fragment=new A();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;

        }
        if(index == 1) {
            Fragment fragment = new B();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        if(index == 2) {
            Fragment fragment = new C();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

**ViewPager code**

```
public class ActivityB extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private String[] item = new String[]{"Information","Work Force","Work Details"};
    private String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
//        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(item[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is my tab c

[image]

After swipe to A and to C again

[image]

Seems like it calling `RetrieveData` again.

Comment: @playmaker420 check again

Comment: code for your retrieveData() function? Btw it's a common practise for function name to start with small case. Only class name should start Big.

Comment: How do you call this framgment from the activity

Comment: @playmaker420 I using swipe tabs

Comment: can you post that code

Comment: @Jiyeh thanks. My retrieveData() is used to retrieve data from `MySQL`. I don't think I need to post that code to here

Comment: @playmaker420 posted. TabAdapter

Comment: Have you tried with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Are you using setRetainInstance in your fragment

Comment: @playmaker420 what's that? Never heard before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setOffscreenPageLimit` of `ViewPager`. It will set how many pages of pager you want to load at first.

Bydefault value for setOffScreeenPageLimit is 1, so it will load current page and next page. In your case it will load `A` and `B`, when you will move to `C` from `B` it will destroy instance of `A`.

try using

```
`pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`
```

it will load current page and 2 more pages so A,B and C will be loaded once .

**EDIT**

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

It clearly means you can set number of pages you want to load at initial level, if you want to load 5 pages at first run, set its value to 4.

Now if you will move from any of pages among 5 pages, `onCreateView()` of `Fragment` will not be called, as its already loaded at initial stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by setting the `OffscreenPageLimit` to 2 to your `ViewPager` instance.
Here is the docs -

```
/**
     * Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
     * current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
     * limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
     *
     * <p>This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
     * of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place
     * on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness
     * of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4)
     * that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for
     * newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.</p>
     *
     * <p>You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts.
     * This setting defaults to 1.</p>
     *
     * @param limit How many pages will be kept offscreen in an idle state.
     */
    public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
        if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                    DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
            limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
        }
        if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
            mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
            populate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're retrieving from the DB every time you swipe to `C`, then you need to clear the list before hand, either in the `onResume` method when you enter the fragment, or in the `onPause` method when you leave the fragment.

This mean either clear your `ArrayList` for example, and make sure its not `static`, or else it means you have to clear your `ListView` by using `listView.setAdapter(null);`. Then don't forget to use `notififyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: can you explain more ? Thanks

Comment: In `RetrieveData(ID)`, you are setting a `List` of some kind and passing that into your `ListView adapter`. Simply clear that `list` at the start of `RetrieveData(ID)` and it should work, no matter what size your `setOffscreenPageLimit` is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't pasted your RetrieveData() code, I assume you read the data into an ArrayList<> or iterate over the cursor.And also there are no other places where you are calling this method except onCreateVie(). Some of the possible solutions may be:

1. If you are explicitly setting viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(x), where x>1, remove that code. By default this value is 1 and view Pager calls createView every time.
2. As you are using FragmentPagerAdapter, once you have loaded your C fragment ideally , it should not be created again, since it should be present in memory and ViewPager will be using that.Check if your onCreateView() is being called every time for C fragment.
3. Please make sure while retrieving your data into a list every time, you are not appending into list instead of clearing the list and then adding it.

Please try above.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers suggest setOffscreenPageLimit but I wouldn't recommend it for 2 reasons.

1) Resources of a fragment in viewpager will not be garbage collected even if it's out of screen. This will cause memory issues in case you have objects taking memory like bitmaps.

2) This approach will not be enough when app goes to background and comes to foreground again.

I suggest saving your data in onSaveInstanceState in each fragment in your ViewPager and check if there is a data saved in onCreate. If there is data, show it. Otherwise, query for the data.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem sometime back, issue was with my code, on fetching date from DB, i was populating the list, and whenever page refreshes it will not creating a new list, it was directly adding the same data in the list which already contains the data and shows two row with same entry. 
To solve this problem, I have cleared my list before populating the data.

Comment: User list.clear(); 
or you can new initialize the list it will clear all the data